# How to validate a array using oval validation framework?

Tags: java, arrays, validation, oval

I have a bean object and want to validate its fields using oval validation framework. 
e.g

```
public class Demo{

    @Range(min=1)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private long[] values;
}
```

As above, I have a field whose type is a array of long. I want to ensure that the array is not null and each element in it must be greater than zero. I don't know how to validate to ensure that its elements are greater than zero. Anyone can tell me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the appliesTo attribute:

```
@NotNull(appliesTo = {ConstraintTarget.CONTAINER, ConstraintTarget.VALUES})
private long[] values;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/* ConstraintTarget.CONTAINER(i.e List) and 
 * ConstraintTarget.VALUES( i.e List elements)
 * it means List shouldn't be null & Its elements shouldn't be null 
 */
@NotNull(appliesTo= {ConstraintTarget.CONTAINER,ConstraintTarget.VALUES})
/*
 * List size should be greater than or equal to 1
 */
@Size(min=1)
/*
 * ConstraintTarget.VALUES means List elements shouldn't be empty
 */
@NotEmpty(appliesTo = {ConstraintTarget.VALUES})
private List<String> roles;
```